# Problem using entity reference to show links to content types associated with a content type

Tags: nodes, entities

I have a content type called module and a content type called lesson.  Module can contain unlimited lessons.

- I installed entity and entity reference module.
- In module, I created a field type of entity reference and set target to node, entity selection to simple and lesson.
- I saved these settings and found I now have select box which allows me to add select lessons when I edit a module type.

However, when I go to the module page I don't see any lessons or even a label for lessons.

Does anyone have any idea how I can troubleshoot this, or what might be wrong?  Also, would i be better trying to create a view rather than using entity selection simple mode?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do would be to check the display settings for your module content type. The field may be hidden or otherwise not configured as you want.

Comment: It's set to label: display above, and format: rendered entity, Rendered as Full content Display links

Comment: So, just to check you went to a module node, edited it and added one or more lessons? Then after saving it you looked at the node view page, and the lessons field doesn't appear?

Have you got the devel module installed, by the way?

Comment: To test, i tried again using 2 newly created content types.  Solution was effectlvely destrying the content types i had and starting again...thanks anyway